# Office 365 Mounted Workspaces disconnect after 2 hours - How to work around?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, microsoft-office-365

I'm trying to get my sharepoint workspaces on office 365 to mount like network drives. I can achieve this following microsoft guidelines, but after a while this fails. The user has to login again to their 365 account, and then remount the drives.

This is time consuming and annoying and with 50+ users you can understand that would produce a bucket load of support calls.

I've given this issue to microsoft to deal with and they have explained that because of the use of form authentication, the drive mapping will time out after 2 hours. (I can't be bothered to find the email just yet - I'll add it to this question if it's requested.)

I'd like to know if others have suffered this issue, and found a workaround? Or is there a way to prevent this disconnection?

Any hints and tips appreciated.

Comment: To clarify you are using the Forms Authentication option and not the SSO option right?

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to utilize the OneDrive sync client.  The token expires on the server side so you have to re-authenticate, and there is not a way to increase that time.  The sync client will handle this request for you, and the folders are available in windows explorer like a mapped drive is.

If you want to keep using mapped drive you will need to develop some sort of script or macro that just goes thru and re-authenticates for you to avoid this. There is a lot of "cons" with that approach.